# How can VBA connect to MySQL database in Excel?

Tags: mysql, excel, vba

```
Dim oConn As ADODB.Connection
Private Sub ConnectDB()
Set oConn = New ADODB.Connection
Dim str As String
str = "DRIVER={MySQL ODBC 5.2.2 Driver};" & _
                                            "SERVER=sql100.xtreemhost.com;" & _
                                            "PORT=3306" & _
                                            "DATABASE=xth_9595110_MyNotes;" & _
                                            "UID=xth_9595110;" & _
                                            "PWD=myPassword;" & _
                                            "Option=3"
''' error '''
oConn.Open str
End Sub

Private Sub InsertData()
Dim rs As ADODB.Recordset
Set rs = New ADODB.Recordset
ConnectDB
sql = "SELECT * FROM ComputingNotesTable"
rs.Open sql, oConn, adOpenDynamic, adLockOptimistic
Do Until rs.EOF
    Range("A1").Select
    ActiveCell = rs.Fields("Headings")
    rs.MoveNext
Loop
rs.Close
oConn.Close
Set oConn = Nothing
Set rs = Nothing
End Sub
```

Doing the similar things in PHP, I could successfully log in to the MySQL server.
I have installed the ODBC connector.
But in the above VBA codes, I failed.
An error turns up. (see the codes where the error exists)

```
$connect = mysql_connect("sql100.xtreemhost.com","xth_9595110","myPassword") or die(mysql_error());

mysql_select_db("myTable",$connect);
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Ranjit's code caused the same error message as reported by Tin, but worked after updating Cn.open with the ODBC driver I'm running. Check the Drivers tab in the ODBC Data Source Administrator. Mine said "MySQL ODBC 5.3 Unicode Driver" so I updated accordingly.

Comment: Even though I updated the driver I'm running, this didn't work for me until I activated  **Microsoft ActiveX Data Objects 6.1 Library**. To do so, In VBE you need to go Tools/References and check Microsoft Active X Data Objects x library

Answer (score 14):

This piece of vba worked for me:

```vb
Sub connect()
    Dim Password As String
    Dim SQLStr As String
    'OMIT Dim Cn statement
    Dim Server_Name As String
    Dim User_ID As String
    Dim Database_Name As String
    'OMIT Dim rs statement

    Set rs = CreateObject("ADODB.Recordset") 'EBGen-Daily
    Server_Name = Range("b2").Value
    Database_name = Range("b3").Value ' Name of database
    User_ID = Range("b4").Value 'id user or username
    Password = Range("b5").Value 'Password

    SQLStr = "SELECT * FROM ComputingNotesTable"

    Set Cn = CreateObject("ADODB.Connection") 'NEW STATEMENT
    Cn.Open "Driver={MySQL ODBC 5.2.2 Driver};Server=" & _ 
            Server_Name & ";Database=" & Database_Name & _
            ";Uid=" & User_ID & ";Pwd=" & Password & ";"

    rs.Open SQLStr, Cn, adOpenStatic

    Dim myArray()

    myArray = rs.GetRows()

    kolumner = UBound(myArray, 1)
    rader = UBound(myArray, 2)

    For K = 0 To kolumner ' Using For loop data are displayed
        Range("a5").Offset(0, K).Value = rs.Fields(K).Name
        For R = 0 To rader
           Range("A5").Offset(R + 1, K).Value = myArray(K, R)
        Next
    Next

    rs.Close
    Set rs = Nothing
    Cn.Close
    Set Cn = Nothing
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks for your codes. But I have been stuck in which I don't know what the server should be. I'm using the MySQL of Xtreemhost and I have been using "sql100.xtreemhost.com". Xtreemhost Support says this is the name for the server. What should I do then?

Comment: have you tried placing your server name in the cell b2 of your excel sheet ??

Comment: Yes, I did, supposedly that the server name is "sql100.xtreemhost.com" but for the driver, I wrote the codes like this: "Driver={MySQL ODBC 5.1.11 Driver}", according to the version on my machine. I was stuck in "Cn.Open" and the error is the same: "Run-time error -2147467259 (80004005) Automation error Unspecified error"

Comment: cn.open tells there is a error in connection  and some times character will not be accepted !! after typing your server name in excel sheet cell b2 = sql100.xtreemhost.com edit the macro code- add a single code before to the server name --->Server='" & Server_Name & "'

Comment: have u created odbc datasource ?? and checked the testconnection??

Comment: Yes, I think you've hinted at somewhere useful. I think I haven't set up MySQL Connector/ODBC Data Source Configuration where I am now stuck in the TCP/IP Server.

Comment: Just got some support from my webhosting server Xtreemhost. The people there say my free plan does not support a remote connection. I have been confused thus far because I have been using PHP to connect to their MySQL database and I thought it was a remote connection (actually NOT because my PHP script page was put on the Xtreemhost server).

Comment: Now I have been writing the VBA script on my Excel file on my local machine and this requires a remote connection to the Xtreemhost MySQL server which my free plan does not support. I think this is one of the reasons (apart from the ODBC configuration mentioned above) causing the error.

Comment: working like a charm. If there is a problem check if b2,b3,b4 etc cells are containing the login details or if table name is correct in code, I had these problems, after that I could access my mysql server (remotemysql.com free mysql server with external access) (+ dont forget to download the ODBC connector from here as first step: https://dev.mysql.com/downloads/connector/odbc/

Answer (score 5):

Just a side note for anyone that stumbles onto this same inquiry...  My Operating System is 64 bit - so of course I downloaded the 64 bit MySQL driver...  however, my Office applications are 32 bit...  Once I downloaded the 32 bit version, the error went away and I could move forward.

Comment: What driver? And where did you download it from? I am sorry, but I am new to trying to get excel to talk to MySQL. I have the same setup, with a 64bit machine and 32bit Office, so I suspect my problem may be similar to yours.

Comment: Drivers can be found at [MySQL Community Downloads page](https://dev.mysql.com/downloads/connector/odbc/).

Answer (score 3):

Updating this topic with a more recent answer, solution that worked for me with version 8.0 of MySQL Connector/ODBC (downloaded at https://downloads.mysql.com/archives/c-odbc/):

```
Public oConn As ADODB.Connection
Sub MySqlInit()
    If oConn Is Nothing Then
        Dim str As String
        str = "Driver={MySQL ODBC 8.0 Unicode Driver};SERVER=xxxxx;DATABASE=xxxxx;PORT=3306;UID=xxxxx;PWD=xxxxx;"
        Set oConn = New ADODB.Connection
        oConn.Open str
    End If
End Sub
```

The most important thing on this matter is to check the proper name and version of the installed driver at:
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\ODBC\ODBCINST.INI\ODBC Drivers\

Answer (score 1):

Enable Microsoft ActiveX Data Objects 2.8 Library

```
Dim oConn As ADODB.Connection 
Private Sub ConnectDB()     
Set oConn = New ADODB.Connection    
oConn.Open "DRIVER={MySQL ODBC 5.1 Driver};" & _        
"SERVER=localhost;" & _         
"DATABASE=yourdatabase;" & _        
"USER=yourdbusername;" & _      
"PASSWORD=yourdbpassword;" & _      
"Option=3" 
End Sub
```

There rest is here: http://www.heritage-tech.net/908/inserting-data-into-mysql-from-excel-using-vba/

Comment: Have enabled the Data Object Library.

And I wonder if SERVER=localhost, how can the application know my SQL server is on xtreemhost SQL?

Still have the same error:
"Run-time error -2147467259 (80004005) Automation error Unspecified error"

Comment: I tried this and got the Error: "Data source name not found and no default driver specified"

Answer (score 1):

Just to update this further

instead of looping through every row and column which takes forever.
try using

```
`Sub connect()
    Dim Password As String
    Dim SQLStr As String
    'OMIT Dim Cn statement
    Dim Server_Name As String
    Dim User_ID As String
    Dim Database_Name As String
    'OMIT Dim rs statement

    Set rs = CreateObject("ADODB.Recordset") 'EBGen-Daily
    Server_Name = "Server_Name "
    Database_Name = "Database_Name" ' Name of database
    User_ID = "User_ID" 'id user or username
    Password = "Password" 'Password

    SQLStr = "SELECT * FROM item"

    Set Cn = CreateObject("ADODB.Connection") 'NEW STATEMENT
    Cn.Open "Driver={MySQL ODBC 8.0 ANSI Driver};Server=" & _
            Server_Name & ";Database=" & Database_Name & _
            ";Uid=" & User_ID & ";Pwd=" & Password & ";"

    rs.Open SQLStr, Cn, adOpenStatic
    Range("A2").CopyFromRecordset rs

    rs.Close
    Set rs = Nothing
    Cn.Close
    Set Cn = Nothing
End Sub
```

this is multiple minutes faster