# VBA: Connect to MySQL and Compare

Tags: mysql, vba, excel

I am coding in VBA to write a macro that essentially does 2 things:

1. Connects to a MySQL database `MYDATABASE`, which has one table
2. Loop and compare all of the values in a column of an Excel Spreadsheet and compare to a column `MyColumn` of a MySQL table `MYTable`

To be specific, my table has three values. An ID, a name, and a number. In my excel sheet, I would have much more information, including ID, address, city, and number. However, there would be no name.

I want to loop through the values of the number column in my spreadsheet, and compare the numbers to numbers in the `MYTable` table. Then, it would pull all associated names to those numbers and place those numbers in an adjacent column in my excel sheet.  For the purpose of this macro... the column I want to loop through is column `C`.

I found this question: [How can VBA connect to MySQL database in Excel?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13558921/how-can-vba-connect-to-mysql-database-in-excel)
which explains how to connect to VBA.

So how would I go about this?

Answer (score 0):

I would load the excel data into a second MySQL table and then write a simple program to do the comparison between the 2 MySQL tables.