# Do I need to install drivers to connect to remote MYSQL database from Excel 2010 via VBA?

Tags: mysql, excel, connection-string, vba

I am trying to build an application for my team the connects to a mysql database in Excel through vba. Below is my code to connect to the mysql database but when it runs it returns the following error:

> [Microsoft ODBC Driver Manager] Data source name not found and no default driver specified

Do I need to install the mysql drivers in order to attach to the db? I was hoping that I wouldn't have to have everyone install them for this to work.

Is there another way or is something wrong with my connection string?

```vb
' Create a connection object.
Dim cnFEYS As ADODB.Connection
Set cnFEYS = New ADODB.Connection

' Provide the connection string.
Dim strConn As String

'Use the SQL Server OLE DB Provider.
'strConn = "PROVIDER=MySQLProv;"

'Use the MYSQL Driver.
strConn = "DRIVER={MySQL ODBC 5.1 Driver};"

'Connect to the database on abc123.
strConn = strConn & "SERVER=abc123; DATABASE=db123;"

'Use an integrated login.
strConn = strConn & " USER=user; PASSWORD=hello; OPTION=3"

'Now open the connection.
cnFEYS.Open strConn
```

Comment: Nope you don't need to install anything see this answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13558921/how-can-vba-connect-to-mysql-database-in-excel

Comment: The post refered by @TomDDD indicates that the MySQL ODBC driver is installed... It makes sense to me that it should be installed

Comment: I uninstalled the mysql ODBC drivers and enabled the Microsoft ActiveX Data Objects 2.8 Library instead of 6.1, but I am not able to connect without installing the drivers. Am I missing something?