# Multiple MySQL Queries to different Cells

Tags: mysql, vba, excel, database-connection

What I try to get to work are different MySQL Queries in one Sub, which should fill different ranges in one table.

Here is what I have got so far:

With the Function "ConnectionDB" I want to connect to the remote Database. In the Sub "QueryDatabase" I open the connection and execute two Sql-queries. The first Sql-query should fill Range A2 and the second query should fill Range D2 in the same worksheet.

I extracted the Sql-strings out of a recorded macro to the remote database and within the recorded macro it worked well.

When I execute my code (see below), Excel is working a while but the adressed cells stay empty. I get no Debug-Error.

So guys, here is where I'm happy about every help I can get to get this working =) Is this even possible the way want it now?

```
Public conMySQL As ADODB.Connection
Public rs As ADODB.Recordset
Public strSql As String

Public Function ConnectionDB()

Set conMySQL = New ADODB.Connection
Set rs = New ADODB.Recordset

conMySQL.Open 
"Driver={MySQL ODBC 5.3 UNICODE Driver}; _
    Server={XXX}; UID=XXX; PWD=XXX; DATABASE=XXX; _
    Option=3; PORT=3306"
End Function


Sub QueryDatabase()

  Call ConnectionDB 

    With Sheets("Energiedaten").Range("A2") 

        strSql = "SELECT Messdaten_0.Terminal, Messdaten_0.Timestamp, Messdaten_0.Value" & Chr(13) & "" & Chr(10) & "FROM BLB_Data.Messdaten Messdaten_0" & Chr(13) & "" & Chr(10) & _
        "WHERE (Messdaten_0.Terminal = 'TerminalX') AND (Messdaten_0.Timestamp>=('" & UserForm1.TextBox1.Text & "') And (Messdaten_0.Timestamp<=('" & UserForm1.TextBox2.Text & "'))" _
        & Chr(13) & "" & Chr(10) & "ORDER BY Messdaten_0.Timestamp" 

    End With

    With Sheets("Energiedaten").Range("D2")

        strSql = "SELECT Messdaten_0.Terminal, Messdaten_0.Timestamp, Messdaten_0.Value" & Chr(13) & "" & Chr(10) & "FROM BLB_Data.Messdaten Messdaten_0" & Chr(13) & "" & Chr(10) & _
        "WHERE (Messdaten_0.Terminal = 'TerminalY') AND (Messdaten_0.Timestamp>=('" & UserForm1.TextBox1.Text & "') And Messdaten_0.Timestamp<=('" & UserForm1.TextBox2.Text & "'))" _
        & Chr(13) & "" & Chr(10) & "ORDER BY Messdaten_0.Timestamp " 

    End With

conMySQL.execute strSql

conMySQL.Close

End Sub
```

Comment: Try following the code in Ranjit's answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13558921/how-can-vba-connect-to-mysql-database-in-excel

Comment: Thx for the hint, but it does not work. I get Run time error 3021 "EOF or BOF is true or the current record has been deleted". The Recordset is empty though

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the `Range.CopyFromRecordset` method. You've already declared `rs As ADODB.Recordset` so you need to open the recordset, write it to the sheet, then close it for each SQL statement.

EDIT: Replaced sample section of code with complete code:

```
Option Explicit

Public conMySQL As ADODB.Connection

Public Function ConnectionDB()

    Set conMySQL = New ADODB.Connection

    conMySQL.Open "Driver={MySQL ODBC 5.3 UNICODE Driver};" _
        & "Server={XXX}; UID=XXX; PWD=XXX; DATABASE=XXX;" _
        & "Option=3; PORT=3306"

End Function

Sub QueryDatabase()

Dim rs As ADODB.Recordset
Dim strSql As String

    Set rs = New ADODB.Recordset

    Call ConnectionDB

    strSql = "SELECT `Terminal`, `Timestamp`, `Value` FROM Messdaten WHERE `Terminal` = 'Extruder' AND `Timestamp` >= '" & UserForm1.TextBox1.Text & "' AND `Timestamp` <= '" & UserForm1.TextBox1.Text & "' ORDER BY `Timestamp` ASC"

    rs.Open Source:=strSql, ActiveConnection:=conMySQL, CursorType:=adOpenStatic, _
        LockType:=adLockOptimistic
    ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Energiedaten").Range("A2").CopyFromRecordset rs
    rs.Close

    strSql = "SELECT `Terminal`, `Timestamp`, `Value` FROM Messdaten WHERE `Terminal` = 'Beschichtungseinheit' AND `Timestamp` >= '" & UserForm1.TextBox1.Text & "' AND `Timestamp` <= '" & UserForm1.TextBox1.Text & "' ORDER BY `Timestamp` ASC "

    rs.Open Source:=strSql, ActiveConnection:=conMySQL, CursorType:=adOpenStatic, _
        LockType:=adLockOptimistic
    ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Energiedaten").Range("D2").CopyFromRecordset rs
    rs.Close

    conMySQL.Close

End Sub
```

Comment: Using this, I get a Run time error (80040e21) "The ODBC-Driver does not support the requested properties" in the first line (rs.Open Source:=.....). Hovering over ActiveConnection:=conMySQL says conMySQL ="Provider MSDASQL.1;" I'm running a 64bit System, could this cause trouble?

Comment: You have replaced the contents of `strSQL` with your own SQL query? I get your error if I use the raw text in my post.

Comment: I now have replaced the contents of strSQL with my own SQL-statement (they work with Tim's answer). Now i get run time error (91) "Objectvariable or With-Blockvariable not defined"...I tried to insert with/end with statements at different places, but it does not work. Is there maybe a "set strSql = New...." missing?

Comment: I have replaced my sample code with your complete code, tweaked to use the `CopyFromRecordset` method and to move around some of the variable declarations.

Comment: Thx, I tried your code with my own SQL-statements, but i still get the same error (91) "Objectvariable or With-Blockvariable not defined"

Comment: Debugger marks this line `rs.Open source:=strSql, ActiveConnection:=conMySQL, CursorType:=adOpenStatic, LockType:=adLockOptimistic`

Comment: It worked fine in my test. The fact that the keyword `source` is lower case might indicate the problem - maybe you've got a variable with the same name. Try `rs.Open strSql, conMySQL, adOpenStatic, adLockOptimistic`.

Comment: Found my mistake, just forgot a line of code ^^ Now it works halfway (as i comment Tim's answer): Results of the Input from TextBox1 are shown in the Worksheet - but only one row (2). Is there a way to define the range another way that all results of the Timestamp-period from the Textboxes are shown? (e.g. Input >= 13:00:00 and <= 13:00:10 should result in 11 values in rows 2 to 12 ("Terminal, Timestamp and Value go allready correctly in columns A-C for the first and in columns D-F for the second query))

Comment: The `CopyFromRecordset` method outputs all the data. Only 1 row means only 1 record. Check your SQL.

Comment: Oh man, what a oversight (two times TextBox1.Text in the statement) of mine :D Thx for your help, it works now! =)

Answer (score 0):

Something like:

```
Option Explicit

Public conMySQL As ADODB.Connection

Public Sub ConnectionDB()

    Set conMySQL = New ADODB.Connection

    conMySQL.Open "Driver={MySQL ODBC 5.3 UNICODE Driver};" & _
                  "Server={XXX}; UID=XXX; PWD=XXX; DATABASE=XXX;" & _
                  "Option=3; PORT=3306"
End Sub

Sub QueryDatabase()

   ConnectionDB

    strSql = "SELECT Messdaten_0.Terminal, Messdaten_0.Timestamp, Messdaten_0.Value" & Chr(13) & "" & Chr(10) & "FROM BLB_Data.Messdaten Messdaten_0" & Chr(13) & "" & Chr(10) & _
    "WHERE (Messdaten_0.Terminal = 'TerminalX') AND (Messdaten_0.Timestamp>=('" & UserForm1.TextBox1.Text & "') And (Messdaten_0.Timestamp<=('" & UserForm1.TextBox2.Text & "'))" _
    & Chr(13) & "" & Chr(10) & "ORDER BY Messdaten_0.Timestamp"

    PutResults Sheets("Energiedaten").Range("A2"), strSql


    strSql = "SELECT Messdaten_0.Terminal, Messdaten_0.Timestamp, Messdaten_0.Value" & Chr(13) & "" & Chr(10) & "FROM BLB_Data.Messdaten Messdaten_0" & Chr(13) & "" & Chr(10) & _
        "WHERE (Messdaten_0.Terminal = 'TerminalY') AND (Messdaten_0.Timestamp>=('" & UserForm1.TextBox1.Text & "') And Messdaten_0.Timestamp<=('" & UserForm1.TextBox2.Text & "'))" _
        & Chr(13) & "" & Chr(10) & "ORDER BY Messdaten_0.Timestamp "

    PutResults Sheets("Energiedaten").Range("D2"), strSql


    conMySQL.Close

End Sub

Sub PutResults(rng As Range, SQL As String)
    Dim rs As ADODB.Recordset
    Set rs = conMySQL.Execute(SQL)
    If Not rs.EOF Then
        rng.Cells(1).CopyFromRecordset rs
    End If
    rs.Close
    Set rs = Nothing
End Sub
```

Comment: I changed my SQL-statements to the following: strSql = "SELECT `Terminal`, `Timestamp`, `Value` FROM Messdaten WHERE `Terminal` = 'Extruder' AND `Timestamp` >= '" & UserForm1.TextBox1.Text & "' AND `Timestamp` <= '" & UserForm1.TextBox1.Text & "' ORDER BY `Timestamp` ASC "     Now it works halfway: Results of the Input from TextBox1 are shown in the Worksheet - but only one row (A2). Is there a way to define the range another way that all results of the Timestamp-period from the Textboxes are shown? (e.g. Input >= 13:00:00 and <= 13:00:10 should result in values in rows from A2 to A12)

Comment: CopyFromRecordset should give you all of the records in your result set.  Are you sure your queries are returning multiple rows?