# Vba variable in SQL

Tags: mysql, vba

Is it possible to have a `vba` variable in `MySQL`?

```
SELECT a,b,c
FROM table1 IN <**someVBAvariable**>
WHERE ...
```

My goal is to be able to re-locate the path of the table to where I want via vba.

EDIT: I understand that VBA can have a global variable, would sql see this?

If this IS possible, would it also work for 2 different sql with 1 vba variable?

Comment: This is not mysql syntax, this is used in ms access. Mysql is not a file based rdbms like access or paradox, I do not think you can do this. Use linked tables or connect to mysql directly using myodbc and ADO.

Comment: As Shadow mentioned, you cannot use a VBA variable within an SQL statement. To do so, you would need to connect with the data source using ODBC or ADO within VBA, and then you could use a variable within the SQL statement.

Comment: So would my best bet would be to update my sql statement from vba file? and not have a vba variable in a sql file

Comment: You can assemble an SQL statement as string from VBA and thus you can include the content of a variable in it. However, I doubt that this would work for mysql from ms access. My point was: either do not use ms access at all or use linked tables from ms access. You can dinamically link tables from VBA code as well.

Answer (score 0):

The whole point of SQL is to define an interface between your code and the database so no you would never want to share information between the two except using a database driver - that would be a huge security risk.

It's trivial to form SQL statements in VBA to execute on MySQL see: [How can VBA connect to MySQL database in Excel?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13558921/how-can-vba-connect-to-mysql-database-in-excel).