# Excel VBA find in Table

Tags: vba, excel

Im having a list of event participants in an Excel Sheet (Col A: Lastname; Col B: Firstname) and a Membership Table with the same plus info colums like birthdate and sex.

No I want to loop through the event list and do some actions on the birthday/sex of the participants. I can express that in MySQL

```
SELECT birthdate, sex FROM members WHERE lastname = LASTNAME AND firstname = FIRSTNAME
```

Where LASTNAME & FIRSTNAME are pulled from the participants table. I can figure out how to create a Loop through the event table but I got trouble on how to pull the data from the Membership Table.

Im just not used to Excel VBA so any help to start me off would be greatly appreciated

So far I got following Loop:

```
Dim participantCount As Integer
Dim sh As Worksheet
Dim rw As Range

Set sh = Sheets(INP_tblakt.Value)
For Each rw In sh.Rows

    If sh.Cells(rw.Row, 1).Value = "" And sh.Cells(rw.Row, 2).Value = "" Then
        Exit For
    End If

   participantCount = participantCount + 1
Next rw
```

EDIT: To Clearify

I got the loop above in wich I want to insert a "function" wich looks up in another sheet the row where `A? = sh.Cells(rw.Row,1)` and `B? = sh.Cells(rw.Row,2)` So that I then can get the value from D? and E? to use it for further calculation.
The VBA function Find does only support the matching of one Colum. I now found MATCH and IDEX but couldnt succesfully implement them.
*(Hopefully this does help to understand the question, Thanks in advance for help)*

Comment: Instead of posting code that does not work, could you try to describe what you would like to achieve? Does it need to be with VBA? Maybe a formula can do this, too.

Comment: Are you needing help with using vba to connect to MySQL? This might help: [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13558921/how-can-vba-connect-to-mysql-database-in-excel)http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13558921/how-can-vba-connect-to-mysql-database-in-excel

Comment: If these two **Tables** are in same file, use formula `VLOOKUP(...)` (provided the table is sorted). But you need combined VLOOKUP to make it work.

Comment: I will try it @PatricK. Is there a similar formula wich returns the row number its found in?

Comment: Yes ROW() formula would do it..

Comment: Sorry I might have mislead you using VLOOKUP given that FirstName and LastName on different column. I have an alternative solution in a moment.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the **members** table is an Excel Table, you can combine **`MATCH`** and **`OFFSET`** to get what you need. There may be a faster way but this is what I got.

Consider below table (on same sheet for screenshot):
[image: TableSample]
`C3` is the cell with formula that finds the DOB for matching FirstName `A3` and LastName `B3` from the **members** table.

The formula is:

```
=IF(MATCH(A3,members[FirstName],0)=MATCH(B3,members[LastName],0),
OFFSET(members[[#Headers],[DOB]],MATCH(A3,members[FirstName],0),0),
"No Match")
```

Since we need to exact match 2 fields (FirstName and LastName), we need the Matches to be on the same position. Hence the condition is:
`MATCH(A3,members[FirstName],0)=MATCH(B3,members[LastName],0)`

Once an exact match is found, we can use `OFFSET` to locate the n'th row from the field we want to extract:
`OFFSET(members[[#Headers],[DOB]],MATCH(A3,members[FirstName],0),0)`
 It means get the value from matched row of table **members** with header "**DOB**". Change the text DOB to the desired header name of your lookup table.

Otherwise "No Match" is returned.
[image: SampleResult]