# Portable remote connection sucking data from MySQL to Excel

Tags: python, mysql, excel, connection-string

Are there any alternatives for Excel users to suck data from MySQL through remote connection without bothering to establish ODBC connection in control panel nor downloading MySQL extensions nor doing anything on user side?

Are there any connectors on MySQL side which would turn data into format readable for Excel? I am looking for dynamic solutions - reading from data base. I am not looking for static solutions like export to csv and import to Excel. Solutions done in any programming language like Python are acceptable.

This ADO connection looked promising for me however still extra work on user side is required at start up: [How can VBA connect to MySQL database in Excel?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13558921/how-can-vba-connect-to-mysql-database-in-excel)

I would like to make a portable Excel file with macro that will work on any computer, in any case.

Answer (score 0):

Hope you are looking for some this as below

```
Sub test1()
    Dim con As ADODB.Connection
    Dim rec As ADODB.Recordset
    Set con = New ADODB.Connection
    Set rec = New ADODB.Recordset
    rec.CursorLocation = adUseClient
    con.Open ("Provider=SQLOLEDB;Data Source=.;Initial Catalog=databasename;user ID=sa; password=sa@123;")
    qry1 = "select * from [dbo].[FARA];"
    rec.Open qry1, con
    For i = 1 To rec.RecordCount
        Debug.Print rec(0), rec(1), rec(2)
    Next i
End Sub
```