# How to connect an excel table to a mysqldb database which is on a virtual server?

Tags: excel, mariadb, vba

I downloaded the MYSQL for Excel applicaton and I installed it succesfully.
But i see I can connect only a local connection.
How can I connect to it my mysqldb database which is on a virtual server in debian?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can VBA connect to MySQL database in Excel?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13558921/how-can-vba-connect-to-mysql-database-in-excel)

Comment: No. I want to connect it to a virtual machine.

Comment: And? Your virtual machine is the server. It's not treated any differently because it's a virtual machine. You just need to make sure the ports are exposed (usually `3306` for MySQL) and reference the server name/ip. Also, make sure your MySQL allows connections externally to the server as well

Comment: I tried it.
3306, localhost, i give it the username+password, and i get this error message : "Connection attempt failed, unable to connect to any of the specified MySQL hosts."

Comment: localhost? That's trying to connect to your local machine. You'll need to reference the vm. Is the vm on the local machine? if so does it share the ip or does it have it's own ip?

Comment: I tried with localhost, and with this : 127.0.0.1 , because this is host,

Comment: Double check your port and ip of the mysql server

Comment: server:mariadb, unix socket:/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock, port:3306